# how to stop <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="2"> after N-times of refreshing the page

Tags: java, html, jsp, liferay

I have added this code to my view.jsp page in my Liferay portlet to refresh it each 2 seconds :

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="2">
```

but after 10 times of refreshing I want it to stop, how can I handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if your n is 3 :

```
 <%
        if (request.getSession().getAttribute("time") == null) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("time", 0);
            out.print("<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"2\">");
        } else {
            if ((Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("time") < 3) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("time", (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("time") + 1);
                out.print("<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"2\">");
            }
        }
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

maintain session on server side to keep track of particular token and its counter and don't send this header on nth time

or use ajax to refresh particular portion of page and maintain javascript variable

Comment: Or... what? What was your third option?

Comment: well there could be number of option, depending on client component on view is used

Comment: No, I meant that you had seemingly forgotten to type something (or it was not rendering as markdown properly)